# Can I propose a Declaration of Friendship?

Tags: civilization-5

Under Civ 5 Gods and Kings, you can't engage in a Research Agreement unless you have a Declaration of Friendship with the other nation. However, I can't find a way to propose a DoF.

Is it possible to propose a Declaration of Friendship? Or is it something only the other nation can instigate?

(I also can't immediately find how to Denounce someone, but that's probably a different matter).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both of these options (Declaration of Friendship and Denouncing) are available under the **Discuss** option when you first open the diplomacy screen to another nation.

I do believe you can't perform either if you're recently performed that action (so you can't propose friendship to a nation who recently rejected a previous proposal), or if the intended state is currently active (you can't propose friendship to your friends).

However, it is apparently possible to denounce friends or befriend those you've denounced, but the first is likely to cause you diplomatic issues while the latter is very unlikely to be accepted.

Finally, these things expire over time, so when that happens you'll be able to suggest a new declaration / denounce them again.

Comment: Ah, I've been looking in the Trade panel. I'll have a go when I next fire it up.

Comment: You can indeed denounce your friends, earning a political demerit with other nations. While I believe you can offer friendship with a nation you have denounced, I doubt they'd accept.

Comment: Also of note, you cannot propose a Declaration of Friendship with someone who you have turned down a DoF recently (not sure how many turns exactly, but *recently*).